# Linear interpolation of monthly data to weekly level in R for several columns

Tags: time-series, interpolation

I have a dataset that looks like the following:

```
Week       Month   A
04-24-2020 04-2020 100
05-01-2020 05-2020 120
05-08-2020 05-2020 120
05-15-2020 05-2020 120
05-22-2020 05-2020 120
05-29-2020 05-2020 120
06-05-2020 06-2020 130
06-12-2020 06-2020 130
06-19-2020 06-2020 130
06-26-2020 06-2020 130
```

I want to create a column based on column A that essentially linearly distributes monthly data that is in A such that the dataset is the following:

```
Week       Month   A
04-24-2020 04-2020 100
05-01-2020 05-2020 104
05-08-2020 05-2020 108
05-15-2020 05-2020 112
05-22-2020 05-2020 116
05-29-2020 05-2020 120
06-05-2020 06-2020 122.5
06-12-2020 06-2020 125
06-19-2020 06-2020 127.5
06-26-2020 06-2020 130
```

I need to do this for several columns similar to A - what is the most efficient way to do this?

Answer (score -2):

If you follow the link below, you will find a complete tutorial on the use of the function `approxfun`, which is what you seek. In particular, look for the `linear` option.

[Link](https://astrostatistics.psu.edu/su07/R/html/stats/html/approxfun.html)